# What is the scope of real-world deep learning applications in 2020?

Tags: deep-learning, applications

2015 was a milestone year for AI--"deep learning" was validated in a very public way with AlphaGo.  However, at the time, the question was raised: "What else is deep learning good for?"

5 years later, I want to gauge:

- How is deep learning applied to real world problems in 2020?  What real world applications is it currently used for?

Answer (score 5):

Deep learning is used to perform language translation in [**Google Translate**](https://translate.google.com/) [[1](https://ai.googleblog.com/2020/06/recent-advances-in-google-translate.html)]. Specifically, Google Translate now uses [transformers](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/7181-attention-is-all-you-need.pdf) and RNNs rather than the original [GNMT system](https://ai.googleblog.com/2016/09/a-neural-network-for-machine.html) (proposed in 2016), which was also based on neural networks. Deep learning is also used in [**DeepL**](https://www.deepl.com/en/translator) (though I cannot find a good resource to cite apart from Wikipedia [[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DeepL_Translator)] given that the system is closed-source), a strong alternative to Google Translate. However, note that, in general, machine translation is still far from perfect and it is probably not adopted to perform serious translations.

**Tesla's autopilot** also uses neural networks [[3](https://www.tesla.com/autopilot)].

> Built on a deep neural network, Tesla Vision deconstructs the car's environment at greater levels of reliability than those achievable with classical vision processing techniques.

**DeepFakes** are also developed using deep learning techniques [[4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deepfake)].

Neural networks are also being used for **chords** and **beat detection** of songs [[5](https://chordify.net/pages/technology-algorithm-explained/)].

Comment: I will be updating this answer, as I gather more information.

Comment: Another application:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DeepFace